# UIBezierPath between draggable views

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to IOS development and currently have an app with a button that creates new instances of a draggable UIView class that I made. I want to make it so there are UIBezierPaths connecting each UIView instance. I want the connecting UIBezierPath lines following as I drag around the UIView instances on the screen. How/Where would I put the drawing UIBezierPath code to gain this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a project some time back that does something similar to what you want. The code to draw the lines in in `drawRect:`, and I use a property observer to redraw the lines when you drag a view. This app puts 10 circles (NodeView instances) in random positions on the screen and adds lines from one to the next. Here's the code that's in a custom UIView class that I use as the controller's self.view,

```
@implementation RDView

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        _nodes = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
            NodeView *aNode = [NodeView new];
            CGFloat hue = arc4random_uniform(1000)/1000.0;
            aNode.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:1 brightness:1 alpha:.7];
            CGFloat xVal = arc4random_uniform(300);
            CGFloat yVal = arc4random_uniform(400) + 50;
            aNode.frame = CGRectMake(xVal, yVal, 20, 20);
            [self addSubview:aNode];
            UIPanGestureRecognizer *panner = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
            [aNode addGestureRecognizer:panner];
            [_nodes addObject:aNode];
        }
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)awakeFromNib {
    for (NodeView *aNode in self.nodes) {
        [aNode addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"center" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    }
}


-(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"center"] ) [self setNeedsDisplay];
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:[self.nodes[0] center]];
    for (int i = 1; i<self.nodes.count; i++) {
        CGFloat dashes[] = {0, path.lineWidth * 2};

        [path setLineDash:dashes count:2 phase:0];
        path.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
        [path addLineToPoint:[self.nodes[i] center]];
    }
    [path closePath];
    [path stroke];
}




- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self];
}
```

You can find the project here, http://jmp.sh/68SdS4f

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to implement. Thank you so much.